# how can I get all header values for a request in firefox addon sdk?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to read headers using the firefox addon sdk using nsIHttpChannel

like..

```
var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
console.log(httpChannel.getRequestHeader("Host"));
```

works but I would like to replicate the complete header and the getRequestHeader only allows asking for one specific line. Do you know of a way to loop true all of them?

I tried serialisazion but that only leads to ({}).

```
for (var key in httpChannel) {
   if (httpChannel.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key + " -> " + httpChannel[key]); 
   }
```

list only Attributes but not the headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
httpChannel.visitRequestHeaders(function(header, value){
  // do something
});
```